# Updating my shopping cart list in android

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a shopping cart app in Android and i followed this tutorial http://www.androiddom.com/2011/06/android-shopping-cart-tutorial-part-2.html
and I am facing one problem now.

When I set a quantity of an item and click `setquantity`, it adds the item to the list `SHOPPING_CART_ACTIVITY`, but if I want to change the quantity now, I should click the same item in the cart and it will redirect me to the specific item's page, `PRODUCT_DETAILS_ACTIVITY`.

However if I change the quantity, it takes it to be a new quantity. and even the old one exists.

I have checked the entire code, and I think a flaw occurs in `PRODUCT_DETAILS_ACTIVITY` (a new object is created every time). I tried the `notifyDataSetChanged` but it was of no use.

Can somebody please tell what can be done?

`shoppingcartactivity`.(here appears the  final list of products in the cart and clicking on an item in the list will redirect me to that particular page)

```
final ListView listViewCatalog = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewCatalog);
    mProductAdapter = new ProductAdapter(mCartList, getLayoutInflater(), true);
    listViewCatalog.setAdapter(mProductAdapter);

    listViewCatalog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Intent productDetailsIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),ProductDetailsActivity.class);
            productDetailsIntent.putExtra(ShoppingCartHelper.PRODUCT_INDEX, position);
            startActivity(productDetailsIntent);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Refresh the data
    if(mProductAdapter != null) {
        mProductAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

`productdetailsactivity`. Each time when I click an item in the cart to change quantity, it treats to be a new entry (so it shows that currently in cart is 0) every time and the previous quantity item ie the old item is also present.

```
    // inside onCreate method....
    LayoutInflater li;

    int productIndex = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(
            ShoppingCartHelper.PRODUCT_INDEX);

    String PRODUCT_STRING="";
    PRODUCT_STRING = getIntent().getExtras().getString("PRODUCT_STRING");

    switch (PRODUCT_STRING) 
    {
    case "Laptops":
    //  catalog = get laptop catalog 
        break;

    case "Phones":

    //  catalog = get phones catalog 
        break;
    }

    final Product selectedProduct = (Product) catalog.get(productIndex);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
             "Inside selected product obj", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    productImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageViewProduct);

    productTitleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewProductTitle);

    productDetailsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewProductDetails);

    productImageView.setImageDrawable(selectedProduct.productImage);

    productTitleTextView.setText(selectedProduct.title);
    productDetailsTextView.setText(selectedProduct.description);

    // Update the current quantity in the cart
    TextView textViewCurrentQuantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCurrentlyInCart);

    textViewCurrentQuantity.setText("Currently in Cart: "
            + ShoppingCartHelper.getProductQuantity(selectedProduct));

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "quantity "+ ShoppingCartHelper.getProductQuantity(selectedProduct), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // Save a reference to the quantity edit text
     final EditText editTextQuantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextQuantity);
    Button setQuantity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonAddToCart);
    setQuantity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            quantity = Integer.parseInt(editTextQuantity.getText().toString());
            ShoppingCartHelper.setQuantity(selectedProduct, quantity);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

shopping cart helper.....

```
public static void setQuantity(Product product, int quantity) {
    // Get the current cart entry
    ShoppingCartEntry curEntry = cartMap.get(product);   gives null for the every entry

    // If the quantity is zero or less, remove the products
    if(quantity <= 0) {
        if(curEntry != null)
            removeProduct(product);
        return;
    }

    // If a current cart entry doesn't exist, create one
    if(curEntry == null) {
        curEntry = new ShoppingCartEntry(product, quantity);
        cartMap.put(product, curEntry);
        return;
    }

    // Update the quantity
    curEntry.setQuantity(quantity);
}

public static int getProductQuantity(Product product) {
    // Get the current cart entry
    ShoppingCartEntry curEntry = cartMap.get(product); 

    if(curEntry != null)
        return curEntry.getQuantity();

    return 0;
}

public static void removeProduct(Product product) {
    cartMap.remove(product);
}

public static List<Product> getCartList() {
    List<Product> cartList = new Vector<Product>(cartMap.keySet().size());
    for(Product p : cartMap.keySet()) {
        cartList.add(p);
    }

    return cartList;
}
}
```

productadapter.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewItem item;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        item = new ViewItem();

        item.productImageView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ImageViewItem);

        item.productTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.TextViewItem);

        item.productQuantity = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewQuantity);

        convertView.setTag(item);
    } else {
        item = (ViewItem) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Product curProduct = mProductList.get(position);

    item.productImageView.setImageDrawable(curProduct.productImage);
    item.productTitle.setText(curProduct.title);

    // Show the quantity in the cart or not

    if (mShowQuantity) {
        item.productQuantity.setText("Quantity: "
                + ShoppingCartHelper.getProductQuantity(curProduct));
    } else {
        // Hid the view
        item.productQuantity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewItem {
    ImageView productImageView;
    TextView productTitle;
    TextView productQuantity;
}
```

Comment: The code snippets are not enough to understand the code, can you post ShoppingCartHelper.java code.

Comment: i have attached the shoppingcarthelper..

Comment: Seems code of ShoppingCartHelper.java file correct. check curEntry is null or not because in that case you added a new entry into list.

Comment: post your adapter code. It could be there you got the duplicates because lists on Android reuse UI objects. You are expected to reuse convertView rather than create a new one if it is not null. Want to see how it look like ?

Comment: i have for instance reused it, but cant determine why curEntry becomes null everytime.

Comment: Have you checked curEntry ? is it null everytime ? want to see your adapter code getView()

Comment: Can you please also add how you declare `cartMap`, and have you checked that since it is a static, there isn't some other code that re-initialises it?

Comment: what is `catalog`? do you load stuff from database? in which case, when do you update it there?

Comment: catalog in PRODUCT_DETAILS_ACTIVITY is nothing but an arraylist which extracts the specific data (for eg if "Laptops" is the PRODUCT_STRING it  extracts all the laptops' content  from SHOPPINGCARTHELPER class).these codes lie above of what i have attached here

Comment: static Map<Product, ShoppingCartEntry> cartMap = new HashMap<Product, ShoppingCartEntry>();

Comment: when i reenter into PRODUCT_DETAILS_ACTIVITY , a new product obj is created and it doesnt even takes the updated quantity                         final Product selectedProduct = (Product) catalog.get(productIndex);